Python Passing values to functions from Nested Dictionary
I'm new to python and playing with Nested dictionary called mydict{} located in a config.py file. i'm trying assign the key, value from nested dictionary using iteration and got the error
    myfunc(key, value['client_id'], value['client_secret'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Basically, i have a dictionary for each client and need to iterate for each.
def myfunc(myval1, myval2, myval3):
    config.ms_auth[TENANT] = myval1
    config.ms_auth[CLIENT_ID] = myval2
    config.ms_auth[CLIENT_SECRET] = myval3;
    <<< piece of logging functions goes here >>>
    with RequestManager(total_indicators, logger) as request_manager:
        logger.info("Start uploading Data")
        request_manager.upload_indicators(parsed_indicators)
        logger.info("Finished uploading indicators")
        
def main():
    tenants = json.loads(config.mydict)
    for key, value in tenants.items():
       myfunc(key, value['client_id'], value['client_secret'])

This is the Dictionary  in config.py file
mydict = {
   'tenant': 'abcd',
   'client_id': 'customerid',
   'cleint_secret' : 'password'
}

any ideas would be highly appreciated..

The value variable is a string, not a dictionary.

Please edit your question to show the exact value of config.mydict

The error you see is because value is a string and not a dictionary. You can only use integers to slice a string.
For example, if you have x="hello world", you can use x[1] to get the second character of the string e. if you use x['value'], you would get the same error.
Double-check your value variable in the code to see what it's returning and if you expect it to be a dictionary, you need to format your original dict in config.py to use a dictionary instead of string
You can use a dictionary like this in your config.py:
{
   YOUR_TENANT: {
      "client_id": YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
      "client_secret": YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET
   }
}


This is exactly in my dictionary config.

@user12336379 Not according to the edit you made to your question. You're missing the nested { and }

@user12336379 yours doesn't have the nested dictionary. another way to access the data you have is to use values functionL https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_values.asp
your code would become: values =  tenants.values()
myfunc(values[0], values[1], values[2])
but I wouldn't recommend this as the values need to be in the correct order in your dict.
